# Is there a way to be legally represented in the UK without being a resident?

Tags: united-kingdom

Is there a way to be legally represented in the UK without being a resident?

Comment: I edited out the request for a recommendation of a law firm and to focus on just the legal question. I also removed the "civil" tag because I'm not sure the OP really knows what that means or why it should be applicable (I'm assuming the question isn't just limited to legal representation for civil law cases). I don't think the remaining question is a terrible one; the answer might be obvious to someone with legal experience but not necessarily obvious to laypersons.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to be legally represented in the UK without being a
> resident?

Pretty much anyone, anywhere in the world, who can afford to hire a lawyer can be legally represented in the U.K. without being a resident.

In order to seek most kinds of affirmative relief (other than disputing the jurisdiction of a particular court over a particular party in a particular case in the first instance), however, the non-resident must acknowledge (at least conditionally subject to a right to appeal a resolution of a jurisdictional issue), the jurisdiction of the court over the non-resident and submit to that court's jurisdiction.

In one famous recent example, the King of Dubai, Mohammed bin Rashid al-Maktoum, who is obviously not a British resident, hired a British lawyer to represent him in a custody dispute with his then-wife Princess Haya, concerning the couple's two children. After two years of litigation, a British senior family court judge, Andrew McFarlane, ruled against him and granted sole custody to his wife in this case [on March 24, 2022](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2022/03/24/dubai-mohammed-prince-court-uk/).

> And if yes, who is a reputable firm which can deal with banking
> related issues.

Law.StackExchange is not an appropriate place to ask for recommendations to specific law firms or lawyers.

More generally, however, the financial industry in the U.K., including its banking industry, is highly geographically concentrated in a financial district in London called [the City of London](https://www.investopedia.com/how-london-became-the-world-s-financial-hub-4589324) (just "the City" to insiders) which has its own mayor and governing body called City of London Corporation.

As a result, most legal professionals (barristers and solicitors alike) with specialized expertise in banking law in the U.K. have offices in or near this financial district.

Comment: +1. Also, you can find non-biased (i.e. not recommendations) listings for solicitors which cover specific legal areas on the [Law Society website](https://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/).